# Stripe Connect: Payment Intent client_secret error

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use flutter_stripe for a stripe connect account, unfortunately I always get the same error: The client_secret provided doesn't match the the client_secret associated with the PaymentIntend.

I checked on my front and backend if the one send and received are the same, so this shouldn't be the issue, any thoughts/ideas?

Idk if it matters but I've used an EU testing cart via a setup intent (which works perfectly fine).

I can also add some code if need but I'm currently unsure whats usefull and what not.

Edit:
Code Samples can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/059c73b24d1861ba44dad123af8b6bbd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Stripe Connect, it is important to remember that you have to do the following:

- instantiate your server-side Stripe library with the secret key of the Platform and pass the Connect account's ID in the Stripe-Account header [0].
- instantiate your mobile Stripe library with the publishable key of the Platform and pass the Connect account's ID in the Stripe-Account header Stripe-Account header [1].

Either your server-side or your mobile-side code is missing the Stripe account header so you would need to fix that. I cannot tell which as you have not shared any code.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#adding-the-connected-account-id-to-a-client-side-application

Comment: Thank you, I forgott to add the identifier to the client as well.

Comment: Still crashes, but the Paymentintent is getting confirmed, I edited the question to include some of the code I've used

Comment: what crashes, please be very specific, what line of code it crashes on, what is the error message etc, what the logged out variable values are, etc

Comment: As soon as you call the dart script, the payment sheet pops up a sec and then crashes with the error mentioned above: Clientsecret doesn't macht payment intent secret (I've paraphrased it now the full one is written in the question). It only throws this error message, I will also a the stack trace to the gist in a sec. But I guess it's rather package related.

Comment: Got it solved sorry for the trouble, I've used the wrong way to pass the account I'd and forgot an edge case like action_required